# VirtualMachine.attach failing

Tags: java, 32bit-64bit, javaagents

I wrote a program that uses the VirtualMachine attach API to dynamically attach to a jar. My machine is 64 bit, and the only reason I can think of that would stop  is because of my messing around with the environment variables of java(no java_home was set and I tried to fix it). Since getting this error, I have reinstalled both the JDK and JRE to no avail. My guess is that it is some sort of problem loading attach.dll, which is 64 bit.

Anyone have suggestions?
Stack trace of error:

```
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotAttachProvider.listVirtualMachines(HotSpotAttachProvider.java:92)
    at sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider.listVirtualMachines(WindowsAttachProvider.java:76)
    at com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.list(VirtualMachine.java:147)
    at me.stoud.*.JVM.<init>(JVM.java:19)
    at me.stoud.helper.*.checkJVM(CheckHelper.java:158)
    at me.stoud.helper.*.initiateChecks(CheckHelper.java:39)
    at me.stoud.start.Launch.main(Launch.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.local.LocalVmManager.activeVms(LocalVmManager.java:148)
    at sun.jvmstat.perfdata.monitor.protocol.local.MonitoredHostProvider.activeVms(MonitoredHostProvider.java:150)
    at sun.tools.attach.HotSpotAttachProvider.listVirtualMachines(HotSpotAttachProvider.java:81)
        ... 6 more
```

Forgot to include: it's a java.lang.InternalError being thrown

Comment: Well without any code.. we can't tell you anything

Comment: @3kings It's a method calling VirtualMachine.list(). There are no arguments for it. I don't see why code is relevant. I could add, but it's literally just a kill to com.sun.tools.attach.VirtualMachine.list()

Comment: Hmm... didn't see that..  I tried the same thing and got an error..   `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.sun.tools.attach.spi.AttachProvider: Provider sun.tools.attach.WindowsAttachProvider could not be instantiated
`

Comment: Do you have attach.dll added to the library.path?

Comment: You mean tools.jar? Becuase thats all i have

Comment: No, I mean attach.dll. It's located in the jdk/jre/lib.

Comment: Ahh.. I added that in.. It worked after that..  Running jdk 1.8.0_92